# How to specify cpu percent of host usage for container in fig

Tags: deployment, docker, lxc, fig

with docker --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = 0 we can specify cpu usage

```
docker run -d --name web --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = xxx
```

There is a way to do it in fig?