# How to restrict cpu usage from host to docker container

Tags: deployment, docker, lxc, fig

I have one VM host in one physical server with many docker containers inside.

Here one fragment of my fig.yml

```
pg:
  image: pg...
redis:
  image: redis...
mongodb:
  image: mongodb...
app:
  image: myapp...
```

I wish set **pg** container use only 25% of host cpu and **app** use only 50% of host cpu and so on.

Could I do it with `fig` or with `docker run` and manage link by hand?

In my case when one of this container is running a costly task it affect the cpu performance of the others ones. But when in the same physical server I have others VM with similar deploy inside the problem increase dramatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify cpu percent of host usage for container in fig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451475/how-to-specify-cpu-percent-of-host-usage-for-container-in-fig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Fig doesn't support setting CPU and memory limitation. Maybe it will support in the future.

I encourage you to experiment with using `docker run -m` for memory limit, and `docker run -c` for CPU shares. These flags will allow you to set memory and CPU values when starting a container. Read more about the flags you can use with docker run here:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

But it can only set when you are create a new container.
After creating container, you cannot change the value.